# OpenSSL1.1のx64ビルドができない

Tags: openssl

Windows 10(x64)でOpenSSL1.1をコマンドラインからビルドするとエラーが発生します。
x86のビルドは通るのですが原因は何でしょうか。
LNK1112発生時はソリューションのプロパティから対象コンピューターを変更するという方法が案内されていますが、コマンドラインからこの設定は変更できるのでしょうか。

ご教授お願い致します。

■現象
perlによるmakefileの生成後、nmakeでエラーが発生する。
エラーメッセージ

```
cl  /Zi /Fdossl_static.pdb /Gs0 /GF /Gy /MD /W3 /wd4090 /nologo /O2 /I "." /I "crypto\include" /I "include" /I "crypto" -D"L_ENDIAN" -D"OPENSSL_PIC" -D"OPENSSLDIR=\"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL\"" -D"ENGINESDIR=\"C:\\openssl\\build\\win\\x64\\lib\\engines-1_1\"" -D"OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32" -D"WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" -D"UNICODE" -D"_UNICODE" -D"_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" -D"_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS" -D"OPENSSL_USE_APPLINK" -D"NDEBUG"  /Zs /showIncludes "crypto\cversion.c" 2>&1 > crypto\cversion.d
        IF EXIST .manifest DEL /F /Q .manifest
        IF EXIST libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll DEL /F /Q libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
        link /nologo /debug /dll  /nologo /debug  /implib:libcrypto.lib /out:libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll /def:libcrypto.def @C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\nm5483.tmp || (DEL /Q libcrypto-1_1-x64.* libcrypto.lib && EXIT 1)
crypto\cversion.obj : fatal error LNK1112: モジュールのコンピューターの種類 'x64' は対象コンピューターの種類 'x86' と競合しています。
```

■環境
VC2019
Perl v5.28.1
ビルド対象Ver. OpenSSL 1.1.1d

■ビルドコマンド
build.bat

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build;%PATH%
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"
rem vcvars64.batでも同様のエラーになる

perl Configure no-asm --prefix=C:/openssl/build/win/x64 VC-WIN64A

nmake install
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

x86ビルド後のゴミファイルが残った状態でビルドしていたためx86オブジェクトのリンクでエラーが発生していました。
OpenSSLのtgzを再展開後ビルドで成功しました。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決とのことですが補足を。

ソースツリーとビルドツリーを分離できます。例えば`build-x86` / `build-x64`ディレクトリをそれぞれ作成すれば生成されたファイルが混線することを回避できます。

```
mkdir build-x64
cd build-x64
perl ..\Configure no-asm --prefix=C:/openssl/build/win/x64 VC-WIN64A
nmake install
cd ..
```

またopensslリポジトリには[`appveyor.yml`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/appveyor.yml)が置かれているのでこれが参考になります。

```
mkdir _build
cd _build
perl ..\Configure VC-WIN64A-masm no-makedepend
nmake build_all_generated
nmake PERL=no-perl
cd ..
```

とかやってるみたいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
お返事が遅れて申し訳ありません。 ビルドモジュールを吐くテンポラリフォルダを別に作れるのですね。
試してみます（現在別の作業に手が取られまだ実際に確認できていません…） ご教授くださりありがとうございました。